# pid/fork vs running system command

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between doing this:

```
pid = fork{ exec 'mpg123','-q', file }
```

and doing this:

```
system "mpg123 -q /home/nemo/sfx/dirty_wood.mp3"
```

I've noticed that the former seems to run many times faster. How? Why? I only just discovered it today here on SO, but it seems like a HUGE improvement for performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fork()` forks off a child process and returns immediately, `system()` waits for the child process to run.

Comment: Ah... Appreciated. Are there any disadvantages to forking it for simple scripting?

Comment: You may have to wait for the forked process to finish. See wait() and waitpid(): http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-fork

Comment: Wow, thank you. Zombie processes everywhere! I've only just now found out about these.

Comment: Good news, you're not alone. Everyone creates zombies on first learning about fork.